# Using APT after installing package by DPKG

Tags: dpkg

As I know "dpkg -i package.deb" installs given package. But why in this case after dpkg, apt is used for installing zabbix modules? Should`t it be installed by DPKG?

```
# wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_5.4-1+ubuntu20.04_all.deb
# dpkg -i zabbix-release_5.4-1+ubuntu20.04_all.deb
# apt update 
# apt install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-apache-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-agent
```

Answer (score 0):

APT download the given modules from the repository. However, these modules can also be installed using DPKG by downloading the package manually from any repo.

> Download it from
> http://mirror.nullivex.com/zabbix/4.5/pool/main/z/zabbix/
>
> and simply install it via dpkg -i package.deb.

Download all the packages like zabbix-server-mysql [http://mirror.nullivex.com/zabbix/4.5/pool/main/z/zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql_5.0.0~rc1-1+jessie_amd64.deb](http://mirror.nullivex.com/zabbix/4.5/pool/main/z/zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql_5.0.0%7Erc1-1+jessie_amd64.deb)
And simply install it via dpkg.

Comment: Ok I understand how to apt works, and I know that packages like zabbix-server-myslq can be installed in simple way by using apt install, but why instruction author downloaded .deb package? It contains newer versions than apt repos?